# CPlex and C++ error: no matching function for call to ‘IloModel::add(bool)’

Tags: c++, cplex

I'm learning how to use CPlex with C++, and due to that, my question might seem stupid. The following algorithm must access a SQlite database, which contains data of soccer players, fetch its contents and then, with CPlex, determine what is the the best lineup according to the average points and their cost inside a fantasy game.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ilcplex/ilocplex.h>

#define TECNICO 0
#define GOLEIRO 1
#define ZAGUEIRO 2
#define LATERAL 3
#define MEIA 4
#define ATACANTE 5
#define NOME 0
#define TIME 1
#define POSICAO 2
#define SITUACAO 3
#define JOGOS 4
#define PRECO 5
#define PRECO_MEDIO 6
#define PONTUACAO 7
#define PONTUACAO_MEDIA 8
#define FALTAS_SOFRIDAS 9
#define ASSISTENCIAS 10
#define FINALIZACAO_TRAVE 11
#define FINALIZACAO_DEFENDIDA 12
#define FINALIZACAO_FORA 13
#define GOLS 14
#define ROUBADA_BOLA 15
#define SG 16
#define DEFESA_DIFICIL 17
#define DEFESA_PENALTI 18
#define PASSE_ERRADO 19
#define IMPEDIMENTO 20
#define PENALTI_PERDIDO 21
#define FALTA_COMETIDA 22
#define GOL_CONTRA 23
#define CARTAO_AMARELO 24
#define CARTAO_VERMELHO 25
#define GOL_SOFRIDO 26
#define ID 27
#define MAX 855

using namespace std;

struct Jogador{
    string nome;
    int id;
    vector<bool> posicao;
    float pontuacao_media;
    float custo;
    bool provavel;
    bool pertinencia;
};

Jogador jogadores[MAX];

int contador = 0;

int callback(void *, int, char **, char **);

int main(){
    sqlite3 *db;
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    char *err_msg;

    int rc = sqlite3_open("jogadores.db", &db);

    if(rc == SQLITE_OK){
        const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM jogador";
        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &err_msg);
    }
    else{
        cout << "falhou ao abrir o banco" << endl;
    }

    IloEnv env;
    IloModel model(env);
    IloCplex cplex(env);

    cplex.setParam(IloCplex::Threads, 1);

    float capacidade_cartoletas;

    cout << "Insira a quantidade de cartoletas" << endl;
    cin >> capacidade_cartoletas;

    //IloNumVarArray itens = IloNumVarArray(env, MAX, 0, 1, ILOBOOL);

    bool itens[MAX];

    IloExpr obj = IloExpr(env);

    int max_posicao[] = {1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2};
    int posicoes_usadas[6];
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        obj += jogadores[i].pontuacao_media*itens[i];
    }

    IloExpr cartoletas_totais = IloExpr(env);

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        cartoletas_totais += jogadores[i].custo*itens[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < MAX; j++){
            posicoes_usadas[j] += jogadores[i].posicao[j]*itens[i];
        }
    }

    model.add(cartoletas_totais <= capacidade_cartoletas);
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        model.add(posicoes_usadas[i] <= max_posicao[i]);
    }

    model.add(IloMaximize(env,obj));

    cplex.extract(model);

    cplex.solve();

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        if(cplex.getValue(itens[i])){
            cout << jogadores[i].nome << endl;
        }
    }

}

int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
    NotUsed = 0;
    vector<bool> aux;
    aux.assign(6, 0);
    if(!strcmp(argv[POSICAO], "Técnico")){
            aux[TECNICO] = 1;
    }
    else if(!strcmp(argv[POSICAO], "Goleiro")){
        aux[GOLEIRO] = 1;
    }
    else if(!strcmp(argv[POSICAO], "Zagueiro")){
        aux[ZAGUEIRO] = 1;
    }
    else if(!strcmp(argv[POSICAO], "Lateral")){
        aux[LATERAL] = 1;
    }
    else if(!strcmp(argv[POSICAO], "Meia")){
        aux[MEIA] = 1;
    }
    else if(!strcmp(argv[POSICAO], "Atacante")){
        aux[ATACANTE] = 1;
    }
    int id = atoi(argv[ID]);
    jogadores[id].id = id;
    jogadores[id].posicao = aux;
    jogadores[id].pontuacao_media = atof(argv[PONTUACAO_MEDIA]);
    jogadores[id].custo = atof(argv[PRECO]);
    jogadores[id].nome = argv[NOME];

    jogadores[id].provavel = !strcmp(argv[SITUACAO], "Provável");
    contador++;
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with g++, but it gives an error:

```
cartola.cpp:116:55: error: no matching function for call to ‘IloModel::add(bool)’
     model.add(posicoes_usadas[i] <= max_posicao[i]);
```

Another thing: I don't have much experience with CPlex, that code was based on a simpler problem my teacher solved using CPlex with C++

Answer (score 1):

You are not modelling your problem using CPLEX modelling variables. This is a very common mistake for beginners. You need to think what data you have whose values you know (e.g. in your database tables) to describe your problem, and what decisions you want your solver (e.g. CPLEX) to make. Then you use normal C++ (or C#, or Java or whatever) variables for the data that you do know, and model those decisions (as yet unknown values) using the modelling variable types (IloNumVar etc) and constraints. You then add those constraints to the CPLEX model and let CPLEX solve the model and choose the best values for your modelling variables.